# gcc c++ command line error-message parser

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

Are there any programs for parsing and displaying in a nice format the c++ error messages generated by gcc.
  I'm really looking for something like `less` that I can pipe my errors into that will collapse the template parameter lists by default, maybe with some nice highlighting so that my errors are actually readable.

(Yes, it's `boost`'s fault I have such incomprehensible errors, in case you were wondering)

Comment: I generally use less myself... that way I can see the very first line of error quickly and in most cases that's enough for me to fix the error. `make | less -S` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[STL Error Decryptor](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) (AKA STLFilt) can help decode them.  I've had mixed results.

Answer (score 0):

Both [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) and [TextFilt](http://textfilt.sourceforge.net/) format and filter complicated c++ error messages.

STLFilt has more features and seems to be better maintained.

TextFilt is more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

This is [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914434/how-to-save-the-error-output-of-gcc-to-file/19326071#19326071) that I have used to resolve this issue, it might not be the best but it helps a lot if you have a heavily templated C++ code.